# change sql result array to wanted format in cakephp

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

i'm getting a array of user names doing a sql query.it's like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [users] => Array (
            [displayname] => Mark
        )
    )
    [1] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Helan
        )
    )
    [2] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Shaun
        )
    )
    [3] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Basu
        )
    )
    [4] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Charit
        )
    )
    [5] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Chris
        )
    )
    [6] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Tony
        )
    )
    [7] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Sam
        )
    )
    [8] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Duck
        )
    )
    [9] => Array ( 
        [users] => Array ( 
            [displayname] => Frank
        )
    )
)
```

i want to recreate the array to this format

`Array ( 'Mark' => 'Mark','Helan' => 'Helan' , ..........,'Frank'=>'Frank')`

How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$users = $this->User->find('list',array('fields'=>array('displayname','displayname')));
```

Comment: I think that that won't give you the displayname as the key

Answer (score 2):

if you use the [find('list')](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1022/find-list) method, you could specify the fields and the result would be a simple key/value array.

Another way to do it is using the [Set Object](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1487/Set) from the Core utility library. See the extract() method

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

It seems that [Set::extract()](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1501/extract) is what you need here, with [array_combine()](http://php.net/array_combine).
Here is an example:

```
// $data contains your find result
$names = Set::extract('/users/displayname', $data);
$formattedData = array_combine($names, $names)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually asking for is [Set::combine](http://book.cakephp.org/view/662/combine) which is basically a combination of what Pierre MARTIN suggests.

```
$names = Set::combine($data, '{n}.users.displayname', '{n}.users.displayname');
```